# How can all the Prophets pray together when different Prophets are in different levels of heaven?

Tags: salat, miraj

When Prophet Muhammad went on the miraj night journey, he was taught prayer by Allah.  All the Prophets prayed and Prophet Muhammad led the prayer, so my question is: How can all the Prophets pray together when different Prophets are in different levels of heaven, like Prophet Musa in 6th heaven and Prophet Ibrahim prophet at 7th?

Comment: The answer is simple each Prophet had a highest level of heaven he could reach or reside in and the prayer toke eventually place at level 1.

Comment: soory i did not understand medi 1saif

Comment: That means they prayed togehter at the lowest level each of theem could stay at.

Comment: Prophets prayed at Aqsa not in lowest heaven

Answer (score 1):

Your Remark: *When Prophet Muhammad went on the miraj night journey, he was taught
prayer by Allah.*

Prophet used to pray in earliest days of revelation, before night of Meraj, 5 prayers were fixed on this night.

> Before the Isra’, the Prophet (blessings and peace of Allah be upon him) definitely used to pray, as did his companions, but there is a scholarly difference of opinion as to whether any kind of prayer was made obligatory before the five daily prayers or not. It was said that what was obligatory at first was prayer before sunrise and prayer before sunset. The evidence for that is the verse in which Allah, may He be exalted, says (interpretation of the meaning): “**and glorify the praises of your Lord before the rising of the sun, and before its setting” [Ta-Ha 20:130]**, and similar verses. Tafseer Ibn ‘Atiyyah (1/204); at-Tahreer wa’t-Tanweer by Ibn ‘Ashoor (24/75)

Your question: *How can all the Prophets pray together when different Prophets are in different levels of heaven, like Prophet Musa in 6th heaven and Prophet Ibrahim prophet at 7th?*

First, all prophets prayed in Aqsa led by Last Prophet, then prophet met some of them in heavens. **Isra precedes meraj** as per evidences from Quran and Sunnah.

Allah caused the prophets to be seen in heavens. Allah has power over all things.

> surely Allah has power over all things. Quran 2:148

Answer (score 0):

In arabic, prophets are "Ma3somoon" which means made to be perfect examples. So they all attained the highest level in jammab.

Comment: actually this is not the meaning of ma3soom.